Responder a preguntas basadas en contenido LEGACY
Responder a preguntas basadas en contenido LEGACY.
Esta pregunta no se basa en si es o no es correcto responder ... busco un punto de partida para el cómo se debería responder a:

Migración de código.
Librerías deprecadas.
Características del lenguaje deprecadas.

El contexto es que "me hace ruido" y no es lo mismo decirle a alguien comenzando un desarrollo cambia todo, a alguien que está en un desarrollo en etapas avanzadas y debe solucionar algo puntual y específico, decirle a este segundo cambia todo es pura maldad si no se cuenta con los recursos.
La idea es ser objetivos y tratar de proporcionar una respuesta acorde y si es posible tomar en cuenta el contexto.
Escucho sus opiniones de cómo lo abordaría, saludos.

No hay nada malo en responder a preguntas con código legacy, deprecado, y obsoleto. Tristemente, aún hay muchas empresas que siguen utilizando cosas bastante anticuadas. Basándose en contexto, añadiría una nota en la pregunta indicando que ese modo ya no es el ideal y apuntando a un método más moderno.
